# What's the origin of "Bock haben"/"Null Bock"?

Tags: etymology, colloquial

I've heard about "Bock haben" or "Null Bock!" which colloquially means to be up for sth. (or not), but where has it developed from? It seems to have started around 1980 (look at [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Null+Bock&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CNull%20Bock%3B%2Cc0)).

Comment: It's older than that, I think, but it was chiefly used in thieves' argot and Gypsy language, i.e. mostly in spoken language. In the late 1970s it was used in youth slang, before finally gaining mainstream acceptance.

Comment: Why the late 1970s? What has happened?

Comment: In the 80's a [Null-Bock-Generation](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-Bock-Generation) started. Maybe some people started to use it and the expression became more know. Later it was used for by more people in all situations.

Comment: Sorry, the Gaunersprache-Gypsy approach doesn't sound logical, more like from one of those pseudo-scientific TV shows. I believe such origin did not play a role in the late seventies.

Comment: "mainstream" acceptance is exaggerated. It is youth slang and only used by young people in careless speech. I never use such an expression.

Comment: @R2D2: Language is seldom about logic. The fact that "Bock" is derived from the *Rotwelsch* word `bokh` (hunger, desire) seems to be generally accepted. When and why it entered the language is another matter, of course.

@rogermue: Duden has it. Regardless of whether you would use such an expression, that's just about as mainstream as you can get.

Comment: I also doubt a late seventies punk had a look in the Rotwelsch (argot) dictionary to create this new buzz word

Comment: Nobody said they did. The word has certainly been floating around, it was sufficiently obscure, parents were bound to not understand it ... all the hallmarks of youth slang, in other words.

Comment: This man claims to be the inventor, unfortunately, we can't ask him anymore: http://www.wer-weiss-was.de/deutsch/woher-stammt-der-ausspruch-keinen-bock-haben#1443993

Comment: Sollte ich raten, hätte ich auf Skat und ähnliche Spiele getippt. Will man das Spiel machen, dann mimmt man in der Regel den Bock auf. Den Bock zu haben bedeutet also das Spiel machen zu wollen. Das passt m.E. besser als Bezüge zum geilen Bock, denn dann müsste es heißen ein Bock zu sein oder bockig zu sein - nicht einen Bock zu haben. Ich bin aber kein Sprachforscher, und dass es einleuchtend klingt besagt wohl sehr wenig - v.a. hätten da ja auch Sprachforscher leicht drauf kommen können, n'est-ce pas?

Comment: @userunknown: es heißt meines Erachtens nach "den Skat aufnehmen", und "Böcke" gibt's nur nach verlorenem Kontra usw.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Die Herkunft von Bock aus dem Rotwelschen ist ein sich lawinenartig verbreitender Irrglaube, der durch die voneinander abkopierenden, frei editierbaren Wikis noch begünstigt und untermauert wird. Aus dem Rotwelsch abstammende Wörter und Wendungen der Umgangssprache (z.B. Knast, Stuss, schnorren, Schmiere stehen) sind seit Jahrhunderten im Umlauf und bleiben daher lebendig. Das Rotwelsch-Wort *Bock* für *Lust*, *Hunger* (von Romani *bokh*) war dagegen nicht mehr im Gebrauch. Ältere Generationen des 20 Jh. haben es nicht verwendet. Von daher ist es sehr unwahrscheinlich, dass dieses archaische Wort der Gaunersprache für die heutige Jugendsprache wiederbelebt wurde. Vielmehr müsste man deshalb in Betracht ziehen, dass sich Ende der 60er eine neue sexuelle Freizügigkeit entwickelte, die sich Ende der 70er durch gesellschaftliche Anti-Bewegungen (z.B. wie Punk) in provokativer Art und Weise auch in der Jugendsprache widerspiegelte und nachfolgend in abgeschwächter und verwaschener Bedeutung in der allgemeinen Umgangssprache akzeptiert wurde. Als Paradebeispiel sei hier *geil* aufgeführt, das im selben Zeitraum seinen Bedeutungswandel erlebte und hoffähig wurde. Analog dazu kommt man über *geiler Bock* auf die Wendung *(einen) Bock haben auf* für (eher sexuell gemeint) *Lust haben auf*. Der Bock steht hier sinnbildlich für (tierische) *Lust*. Das anfänglich auf Partner bezogene *Bock auf jemanden haben* wurde nachfolgend auf alle Dinge verallgemeinert und verlor durch diese Abschwächung damit seine provokative Bedeutung.<sup>[(1)](http://www.staff.uni-marburg.de/~naeser/ra-mat.htm)[(2)](http://tobias-lib.uni-tuebingen.de/volltexte/2001/209/pdf/diss061-080.pdf)[(3)](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=null%20Bock%20haben&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou)[(4)](http://books.google.de/books?id=GqBuAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT35&lpg=PT35&dq=1910%20bokh&source=bl&ots=I32Rg56PKd&sig=F15rfoqvlrR6eMvIb0CG8tRRhW4&hl=de&sa=X&ei=HsReU9O0HM7GtAbXjIDoBA&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=1910%20bokh&f=false)</sup>

Comment: Ich bin nicht überzeugt. Auch die Dissertation von Shelley Ching-yu Hsieh "Tiermetaphern im modernen Chinesischen und Deutschen: Eine vergleichende semantische und soziolinguistische Studie" erwähnt den Ausdruck nur am Rand, und ist wohl auch nicht geeignet etymologische Zweifel in Bezug auf einen bestimmten Ausdruck abschließend und umfassend zu beseitigen.

Comment: Ingmar, warum glaubst du der anderen Version? Wo sind deren wissenschaftliche Belege? Ich habe keinen einzigen Beweis für die Rotwelsch-Theorie gefunden. Stattdessen vermeiden wissenschaftliche Abhandlungen dies oder vermuten eher meine Version.

Comment: Die mir hier vorliegende, auch gedruckte, Sekundärliteratur stuft die Herkunft aus dem Rotwelschen als glaubwürdig ein, manche Autoren versteigen sich zu "Herkunft ungeklärt, vielleicht ..." Um ganz ehrlich zu sein ist mir das Thema aber nicht wichtig genug, um jetzt in die Universitätsbibliothek zu fahren und eine Seminararbeit darüber zu verfassen ...

Comment: @SchcS: du solltest deine Theorie mit Belegen untermauern. In den von dir verlinkten Zitate kann ich keine Hinweise finden, die deine Theorie unterstützen würden.

Comment: Der "geile Bock" entstammt im Übrigen aus dem Französischen *"un vieux bouquin"* und war schon Campe am Anfang des 19. Jahrhunderts bekannt.

Comment: Ich finde die Ausführungen widersprüchlich. "Das Rotwelschwort Bock für Lust..." ist es nicht, aber "analog kommt man auf 'Bock haben auf' für 'Lust haben auf' - doch auf Bock=Lust. Da Rotwelsch selten als Schriftsprache benutzt wird und wurde stelle ich mir die Führung des Nachweises schwierig vor.

Answer (score 6):

From the [German Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Bock):

> Die Bedeutungsvariante „Lust“ stammt aus dem Gebrauch des Wortes im Rotwelschen (Gaunersprache). Dorthin ist es aus dem Romani-Wort bokh für „Hunger, Lust“ eingewandert und hat daher mit dem deutschen Wortstamm etymologisch nichts gemein.

Comment: Why has it become popular around 1980, or do your grandparents use it as well?

Comment: Have a look at [ngram with “kein Bock”](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kein+Bock&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckein%20Bock%3B%2Cc0). It's older than 1980.

Comment: this is simply why books about sheep may contain this pattern as well

Comment: It seems that you're right that most books containing “kein Bock” are about sheep. But there are books with “kein Bock” that means “keine Lust” in 1973 (and “aus Bock” = “weil ich Lust darauf habe/hatte”): [Das Brot mit der Feile](http://books.google.de/books?ei=mXddU6DSBYWItQbWroGYBA&hl=de&id=mIARAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22kein+bock%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22bock%22)

Comment: Btw, *keinen Bock* has more hits.

Answer (score 6):

Hier noch zwei wissenschaftliche Belege für die Herkunft von "keinen Bock haben" aus dem Romani **Bokh**:

> - Der Wortschatz enthält noch einige Hundert Wörter, die in die indische Zeit zurückreichen, ansonsten finden sich viele Wörtter aus den Kontaktsprachen. In die Kontaktsprachen ist wenig eingegangen, vielleicht Bokh 'Hunger' > (keinen) Bock haben (auf).<sup>[L. Hoffmann, Univ. Dortmund](http://home.edo.uni-dortmund.de/%7Ehoffmann/ABC/Roma.html)</sup>
> - Romani ist aber nicht ausschließlich eine Sprache, die entlehnt. Deutsche Sonder- und Geheimsprachen wie Jenisch oder Rotwelsch enthalten, bedingt durch berufliche und soziale Kontakte, mehrere 100 Wörter aus dem Romani, während in der deutschen Umgangssprache wenige Wörter aus dem Romani auftauchen, wie z.B. Zaster / Geld (< rom. saster bzw. sastro / Eisen) oder Bock / Lust (< rom. bokh / Hunger).  <sup>[Romani, Unive. Graz](http://romani.uni-graz.at/rombase/ped/lang.de.html)</sup>

Anders ist die Etymologie der Bezeichnung "geiler Bock", die auch im Französischen bekannt ist (*un vieux bouquin*). Hier ist der *Bock* wohl tatsächlich ein Bild einer animalischen Triebhaftigkeit. Der "geile Bock" wird schon 1700 von Matthias Kramer im "[Das herrlich grosse teutsch-italiänische Dictionarium](http://books.google.de/books?id=E81FAAAAcAAJ&dq=%22geiler%20Bock%22&hl=de&pg=RA1-PA132#v=onepage&q=%22geiler%20Bock%22&f=false)" erwähnt:

[image]

Comment: Danke für die Belegstellen!

Comment: Was man bräuchte, wären Belege von vor 1975, dass Rotwelsch-Bock noch im Sprachgebrauch war (evtl. nur regional). Falls doch ausgestorben, wäre auch eine Zufallsgleichheit wahrscheinlich, und diese Belege könnten durch falsche Schlussfolgerungen entstanden sein, vielleicht sogar unter Einfluss des "Irrglaubens"... :)

Comment: @falkb: mehr und älter geht nicht...

Answer (score 2):

Das Hindi Wort für "Hunger" ist भूख - ausgesprochen "puk". Man kann es gleichzeitig für "Lust haben" benutzen.
Die Verbindung zwischen Deutsch-Rotwelsch-Romani ist also ganz eindeutig.

Answer (score 0):

"Bock haben" kommt vom Romani "bokhajlem", bedeutet da "hungrig geworden sein" und ist wahrscheinlich über das Rotwelsch ins Deutsche gekommen.