# Verwendung von "null" statt "keine(n)"

Tags: word-usage, etymology

Die Redewendung "null Bock" scheint in den 1980-er Jahren aufgekommen zu sein. Meine Frage bezieht sich nicht auf das Wort "Bock" wie in [What's the origin of "Bock haben"/"Null Bock"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11709/whats-the-origin-of-bock-haben-null-bock) , sondern auf das Wort "null", das hier anstatt "keinen" (Bock) verwendet wird. Inzwischen hat es sich offenbar allgemein durchgesetzt, beispielsweise hört man "null Ahnung", "null Problemo" usw. Vor kurzem kündigte Bundesinnenminister Seehofer "[Null Toleranz für Rechtsextremisten](https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/kurzmeldungen/DE/2020/10/rede-hh-bundestag.html)" an. Woher kommt das Wort "null" in diesem Kontext? Ist es ein Anglizismus oder hat es seinen Ursprung im deutschen Sprachraum?

**Ergänzung:**

Die Frage nach einem möglichen Anglizismus stelle ich, weil auch im Englischen "zero" statt "no" vorkommt. Beispielsweise wurde in den 1990-er Jahren in New York die "[Zero Tolerance Policy](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nulltoleranzstrategie)" zur Kriminalitätsbekämpfung verkündet. [Zitat](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=Zero+tolerance) aus dem *Online Etymology Dictionary*: Zero tolerance first recorded 1972, originally U.S. political language.

Das klingt nicht nach Jugendsprache wie im Deutschen.

Comment: Ein Anglizismus ist es sicher nicht, s. Sektion _Etymologie_ in [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/null).

Comment: Die Wiktionary verweist auf den Duden, um die Herkunft "über englische" zu rechtfertigen. Der Duden zeigt aber nichts, jemand sollte das korrigieren.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Das Wort "null" als solches ist natürlich kein Anglizismus, mir ging es um die Kombination mit anderen Begriffen. Die Sektion Etymologie in DWDS gibt dazu keine Auskunft.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Es geht hier nicht darum, ob _null_ ein Anglizismus ist, sondern ob die spezifische Verwendung ein Anglizismus ist. Darüber sagt der Eintrag im DWDS nichts, wenn ich das richtig sehe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laut Google Ngram Viewer lässt sich die Phrase »null Bock« schon 1975 schriftlich belegen, und bereits 1980 wurde sie (zumindest in Druckwerken) häufiger verwendet, als »null Problem« oder »null Problemo« jemals in irgend einem Jahr.

»Null Ahnung« war sogar vor »null Bock« da, aber nur 1 Jahr davor (erste schriftliche Erwähnung: 1974), entwickelte sich anfangs langsamer, lag 2000 bis 2005 gleichauf mit »null Bock« und ist seitdem der häufigste der hier behandelten Begriffe.

»Null Problemo« taucht erstmal 1985 in schriftlichen Dokumenten auf, vermutlich in Anlehnung an »null Bock« und »null Ahnung«, also deutlich nach »null Bock« und »null Ahnung« (rund 10 Jahre später)), aber klar belegbar bereits drei Jahre **vor** dem Start der Fernsehserie ALF (Ausstrahlung der deutschen Fassung im ZDF und ORF: 1988 bis 1991).

Die Macher/Übersetzer von ALF haben den Spruch »null Problemo« also nicht erfunden, haben aber einen Trend aufgegriffen und wegen der großen Reichweite damaliger Fernsehserien intensiv verstärkt. Dadurch entstand aber auch eine sehr starke Verbindung zwischen »null Problemo« und ALF. Immer wenn jemand diesen Spruch verwendet hat, hatte man das Bild von ALF im Kopf.

Dieser Effekt wurde nach 1991, als die letze der genau 100 im deutschsprachigen Fernsehen ausgestrahlten Folgen gesendet wurde, über die Jahre natürlich wieder schwächer, hält aber, zumindest bei jenen Menschen, die damals die Serie gesehen haben (also z.B. auch bei mir selbst), bis heute an. Und dieser Effekt hat nach 1991 wie eine Bremse auf die trotzdem langsam wachsende Verbreitung gewirkt. Daher erreichten »null Problem« und »null Problemo« auch zu keiner Zeit die Häufigkeiten von »null Bock« und »null Ahnung«.

Die These, dass zuerst ALF da war, dann der Spruch »null Problemo«, und erst daraus dann »null Bock« und »null Ahnung« entstanden sein sollen, lässt sich also nicht halten.

[image: Ngram: null Problem, null Problemo, null Bock, null Ahnung]
[image: Ngram: null Problem, null Problemo]

Bleibt nur noch zu klären, warum man in den 1970er Jahren anfing, »null Ahnung« (und gleich darauf »null Bock«) zu sagen.

Ich war 1975 10 Jahre alt und habe gerade begonnen in der Schule Englisch zu lernen. Und ich erinnere mich noch sehr lebhaft daran, dass ich es seltsam fand, dass man im Englischen so einfallslos war, für »kein(e)«, »nicht« und »nein« dasselbe Wort zu verwenden. Mit meinen Freunden haben wir uns bei diesen und ähnlichen Seltsamkeiten der neuen Fremdsprache oft den Spaß gemacht zu überlegen, wie jemand, der Englisch spricht und Deutsch als Fremdsprache lernt, damit umgehen würde. Wir dachten uns, dass die Briten und Amis, weil sie ja keine Ahnung von Deutsch haben, das immer irgendwie verwechseln müssten, und dann auf Fragen statt mit »nein« mit »keine« Antworten würden, oder dass sie eben statt »ich habe keine Ahnung« »ich habe nein Ahnung« sagen würden.

Vielleicht ist aus ähnlichen Späßen von Kindern irgendwo anders im deutschen Sprachraum die Phrase »null Ahnung« entstanden, die ja ganz genau ausdrückt, dass derjenige, der sie ernsthaft verwendet, absolut keine Ahnung hat. Und dieser Witz, der in dieser Formulierung steckt, hat dann vermutlich zu einer raschen Verbreitung in der Jugendsprache geführt. Die Phrase hat sich sogar über längere Zeit gehalten und ist später dann in den allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch integriert worden.

»Null Bock« ist wohl auch in der Jugendsprache entstanden, wobei das Wort »null« - wie ich vermute - von »null Ahnung« inspiriert war.

Das Wort »Problemo« (mit O am Ende) habe ich übrigens schon lange vor ALF gehört, nämlich von jugoslawischen Gastarbeitern, die auch in deutschen Sätzen immer wieder »nemo problemo« gesagt haben um zu bestätigen, dass sie eine gestellte Aufgabe problemlos lösen würden. Ich vermute, dass das auch der Ursprung für das angefügte O in der Phrase »null Problemo« ist.

Comment: Ich weiß nicht, woher du die These nimmst, dass ALF zuerst da gewesen sein sollte. Von mir kommt sie jedenfalls nicht. Die reinen Zahlen über schriftliche Erwähnungen sagen nicht viel aus. Schriftliche Veröffentlichungen zwischen 1970 und Mitte der 1990-er Jahre dürften kaum vergleichbar mit dem sein, was seit dem Einzug des Internets in jeden Haushalt am Ende der 1990-er Jahre schriftlich veröffentlicht wird. Ersteres dürfte im Zusammenhang mit *null Bock* vor allem Schmähkritik an jugendlicher Einstellung gewesen sein.

Comment: Allerdings - und daher ist deine Antwort dennoch interessant - bekleidet die *Null-Bock-Generation* der 1970-er Jahre heute Ministerämter. Da ist die Sprache möglicherweise mit den Sprechern einfach in das Establishment hineingewachsen.

Comment: Danke für die ausführliche Antwort! Nach dieser (für mich plausiblen) Theorie wäre dann also "null" kein Anglizismus (weil im deutschen Sprachraum entstanden), gleichwohl aber durchs Englische motiviert.

Answer (score 1):

[Dwds](https://www.dwds.de/wb/null) listet *null* als umgangssprachliches, jugendprachliches Synonym zu *kein*. Unter den Hinweisen zur Etymologie wird mit Hinweis auf die im 16. Jahrhundert entstandene rechtssprachliche Formel *null und nichtig* (für rechtlich ungültig) u.a. aufgeführt:

> entlehnt aus lat. nūllus ‘keiner’.

Die heutige Verwendung geht wahrscheinlich auf die deutschsprachige Synchronisation der in den 1980-er Jahren sehr populären Fernsehserie [ALF](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alf_(Fernsehserie)) zurück.

Ein wesentliches Merkmal dieser **a**ußerirdischen **L**ebens**f**orm, der u.a. der Spiegel "anarchischen Witz" [bescheinigt](https://www.spiegel.de/kultur/kino/dvd-box-alf-ein-alien-so-destruktiv-wie-der-mensch-a-660483.html), und damit wesentliche Grundlage der Komik ist ihr Unverständnis für die oft bieder anmutenden Sichtweisen insbesondere des Vaters der Familie, in der ALF lebt. Situationen, die diesen Vater nicht selten an den Rand der Verzweiflung treiben, kommentiert ALF im englischsprachigen Original immer wieder mit einem hilfsbereiten

> no problem

und entschärft die Situation durch wohlgemeinte Lösungen, die dann allerdings in der Regel zu neuem Chaos führen. In der deutschen Synchronfassung wurde daraus

> null problemo.

Dass diese Wendung schnell Eingang in die Jugendsprache der damaligen Zeit fand, ist nicht verwunderlich, wenn man bedenkt, dass zum einen damals das Fernsehen insgesamt in etwa so anarchisch war wie Vater Tanner und zum anderen mit den wenigen Sendern (und ohne Internet) einen wesentlich größeren Einfluss auf das öffentliche Leben hatte als heute. Da ALF als sehr liebevolle Figur gezeichnet wird, hatten auch Leute, die dem Jugendalter schon entwachsen waren, dem Spruch

> null problemo

als harmlose Aufforderung, die Dinge nicht so verbissen zu sehen, selten mehr als ein Lächeln entgegenzusetzen. Ich erinnere mich sehr genau, dass auch (aus jugendlicher Sicht) ältere Personen wie Eltern und Lehrer diese Bemerkung gar nicht so selten benutzten. Schließlich war es in den 1980-er Jahren durchaus üblich, solche Familiensendungen im Vorabendprogramm gemeinsam im Kreise der Familie anzusehen.

Ohne es belegen zu können halte ich es für sehr wahrscheinlich, dass die breitere Verwendung von *null* im Sinne von *überhaupt kein* dort ihren Anfang genommen hat.

Comment: Alf hat die Redewendung "Null Problemo" geprägt, unbestritten. Dass er auch die "null" aus der Jugendsprache in der breiten Bevölkerung Bevölkerung zumindest richtig bekannt machte, halte ich ohne Belege für problematisch. Ausdrücke wie "null Bock" lassen sich etwa deutlich früher finden. Eine frühere Verbreitung der Wortbedeutung in der Bevölkerung ist also wahrscheinlich. Nicht zuletzt durch die bereits von dir angesprochene Redewendung.

Comment: @mtwde Bekannt oder nicht ist ja hier nicht die Frage. Es geht darum, ob es in der breiten Bevölkerung alltäglich verwendet wird. Für die Verbreitung eines Ausdrucks spielt es eine wesentliche Rolle, wie dieser Ausdruck besetzt ist. *Null Bock* dürfte umso negativer besetzt gewesen sein, je weiter man zurückschaut. Das ist spätestens seit ALF für *null problemo* nicht der Fall. Daher meine Vermutung, dass der Übergang in den allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch damit sehr viel flüssiger verlief.

Comment: Danke für die Antwort (+1). Für mich bleibt allerdings die Frage offen, warum aus dem englischen "**no** problem" das deutsche "**null** Problemo" wurde. Dass es sich dann mit ALF durchgesetzt hat, ist durchaus plausibel.