# Was ist die Bedeutung von 'Ich habe Bock'?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, vocabulary

Ich habe ein Video geguckt und ein Person sagte "Ich hab' mir Bock" und ich war ein bisschen verwirrt darüber, denn ich fand, dass 'Bock' schwierig ins Englische zu übersetzen ist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the origin of "Bock haben"/"Null Bock"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11709/whats-the-origin-of-bock-haben-null-bock). also: [Bock haben](https://www.dict.cc/?s=bock+haben)

Comment: Your title and your question do not match. Are you sure the person said "Ich hab' **mir** Bock"? Can you link the video?

Comment: Sehe ich wie mtwde. Außerdem stellt der Link die Frage nach der Herkunft, nicht nach der Bedeutung.

Comment: Kein Duplikat, aber "Needs details or clarity" weil unklar ist, ob "Ich habe Bock" oder "Ich hab' mir Bock" gemeint ist. Ein Link zur Quelle würde weiterhelfen.

Comment: @mtwde die Bedeutung wir aber auch im anderen Thread erklärt.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: The accepted answer for the other question was in German, so I think it still counts as a duplicate. I don't really know what the OP had in mind, basically asking in German to translate something into English. I'm thinking the "Ask in the language you want the answer" rule is not well understood by newbies; perhaps the help text should be clarified.

Answer (score 3):

In this context "Bock" would have the meaning of "Lust", meaning something like "I am up for it"